# Want to set dropdown list to the first value in a datatable asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have a drop down list, GroupDropDown, and a data table, GroupDataTable. I have a select statement that only produces one value, i want to set the drop down selected value to the one value in the data table. I've tried a bunch of different stuff and still can't seem to figure it out. Like most errors, I'm sure I am making a silly mistake, but here is my code:

```
Dim Region As String = Encryption64.Decrypt(Request.QueryString("Region"))
Dim MySqlString As String = "Select GROUPNAME, GROUPOWNERSHIP from Table1 where GROUPNAME like '%" & Region & "%'"

Dim GroupDataTable As DataTable = OleFun.GetMyDataTableString(MySqlString, 2)

GroupDropDown.DataSource = GroupDataTable
GroupDropDown.DataBind()

For Each row As DataRow In GroupDataTable.Rows
    Response.Write(row(1))
Next

GroupDropDown.SelectedValue = ?

GetData()
```

Thanks in advance for your responses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select a row and column from a DataTable by name or index and use that value as the `SelectedValue`

```
GroupDropDown.SelectedValue = GroupDataTable.Rows[0]["myColumn"].ToString();

//or by column index

GroupDropDown.SelectedValue = GroupDataTable.Rows[0][7].ToString();
```

VB

```
GroupDropDown.SelectedValue = GroupDataTable.Rows(0)("myColumn").ToString
```